# How can I make peace with contravariance?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

My question is a bit vague, but I hope it can be answered in a good way.

Various arguments involving contravariance sometimes trip me up when coming up with proofs in algebraic geometry and related subjects. For example:

> Let $V \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n(k)$ and $W \subseteq \mathbb{A}^m(k)$ be algebraic sets. Show that for each $k$-algebra homomorphism $\phi: O(W) \rightarrow O(V)$, there exists a polynomial map $f: V \rightarrow W$ such that $\phi(g) = g \circ f$, for all $g \in O(W)$.

Here is a proof: Write $(x_i)$ and $(y_j)$ for the coordinates on $V$ and $W$ respectively. Define $f = (f_1, \dots, f_m)$, where for each $j$, $f_j(x_1, \cdots, x_n) = \phi(y_j)$. Then, $\phi(y_j) = y_j \circ f$ by construction, so that $\phi(g) = g \circ f$ for all $g$ (because $g$ is a $k$-algebra homomorphism).

In some sense I answered my own question, but my real frustration is that it took me twenty minutes of confusion to write that down, despite the fact that the argument is essentially tautological, and despite a fair amount of practice on similar questions.

Is there a good way to intuitively master these sorts of arguments, so that one can produce them on demand without becoming confused?

Comment: I can't quite see how contravariance itself made this problem hard, but perhaps I can just say "You look like you're getting the hang of it. The first encounters with a certain type of proof can be harder than the rest. Try not to be frustrated by feelings of 'feel like I'm not getting it fast enough.' This is natural in the course of learning, and you eventually get past it. "

Comment: @rschwieb: Thanks, I appreciate the encouragement, but I should add that I have a fair bit of experience and for whatever reason I often get hung up on this particular flavor of argument.

Comment: I don't think of this particular problem as being specific to modern algebraic geometry -- somehow it's a problem throughout geometry, right? If I have a map $f\colon X \to Y$ and a function $g$ on $Y$ (I'm being deliberately vague) then I can pull that back to get a function on $X$. This happens on topological spaces, manifolds, analytic spaces, etc.